# Capture audio from JavaScript and recognize it with Google Speech API

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, html5-audio, google-speech-api

I use https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs library to capture the audio.

```
recorder.exportWAV((data)->
        fileReader = new FileReader;
        fileReader.onload = (blob) ->
            blob = blob.target.result;
            send(btoa(blob))
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(data)
      )
```

But I got the following error: `Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.`

When I use `exportMonoWAV` the quality of audio is very low and recognition results are poor.

How can I pass Mono WAV without losing the quality?

Comment: You can share the file to give others better idea about the problem. Bad quality is usually related to bad microphone, not to the mono/stereo in wav format.

Answer (score 1):

By default Recorder.js records 2 channel audio (by duplicating the mono channel that comes from the mic). To record mono sound instead (and halve the size) use `numChannels:1` in the Recorder.js constructor like this:

`var rec = new Recorder(source,{numChannels:1})`

`numChannels` is an undocumented feature of Recorder.js but shows up in [its js code](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/src/recorder.js).

Source (my article): https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/